# Scrape web page <ul> <li> (Python)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

## Question:

There is a website https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/#page=1 with a list `<li>` under a `<ul>` each item in the list contains a `<div>` with class *title* in that class there are 2 more `<div>` elements the first one has some text example *3.4 GHz 6-Core (Pinnacle Ridge)* i want to remove all text not in the brackets to get *Pinnacle Ridge*. After the list is scraped i want to move onto the next page by changing *#page=*.

## Code:

I'm not too sure an only have snippets but here it is:

from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

```
r = session.get('https://au.pcpartpicker.com/product/cpu/overall-list/#page=' + page)

table = r.html.find('.ul')

//not sure find each <li> get first <div>

junk, name = div.split('(')

name.replace("(", "")

name.replace(")", "")
```

## Expected Result:

I want to loop through each page until there are none left finding each list and getting the name it doesn't need to be saved as i have code to save it when it is created.

If you need any more information please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is dynamic, thus, you will have to use `selenium` to produce the desired results:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time, re
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromdriver')
d.get('https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/#page=1')
def cpus(_source):
  result = soup(_source, 'html.parser').find('ul', {'id':'category_content'}).find_all('li')
  _titles = list(filter(None, [(lambda x:'' if x is None else x.text)(i.find('div', {'class':'title'})) for i in result]))
  data = [list(filter(None, [re.findall('(?<=\().*?(?=\))', c.text) for c in i.find_all('div')])) for i in result]
  return _titles, [a for *_, [a] in filter(None, data)]


_titles, _cpus = cpus(d.page_source))
conn.executemany("INSERT INTO cpu (name, family) VALUES (?, ?)", list(zip(_titles, _cpus)))
_last_page = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('#page\=\d+')})[-1].text
for i in range(2, int(_last_page)+1):
   d.get(f'https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/#page={i}') 
   time.sleep(3)
   _titles, _cpus = cpus(d.page_source))
   conn.executemany("INSERT INTO cpu (name, family) VALUES (?, ?)", list(zip(_titles, _cpus)))
```

Comment: I just realized is it also possible to grab the name each time so i can match it into my database?

Comment: What are the 2 variables for name and family? Is it _titles?

Comment: @Uskompuf Sorry for being unclear. The output is a list of dictionaries, and the key of each dictionary is title, and the value is the CPU name.

Comment: because as is your program doesn't print anything is there anyway to split the name and family into 2 variables and they get updated each time there is a new one in a loop so i can insert them into MySQL?

Comment: @Uskompuf Please see my recent edit. Now, there are variables `_titles`, `_cpus`, each lists storing the titles and cpus at each iteration.

Comment: @Uskompuf Glad to help!

Comment: ok im not sure if im doing this right i add data to my MySQL table with sql = "UPDATE cpu SET family = " + family + " WHERE name = " + name +";" so i need to run that for every new cpu and family is there any way to do that with the 2 lists?

Comment: @Uskompuf Can't you simply insert each name with its corresponding CPU family? Please see my recent edit.

Comment: I am using the name to match the family with the correct row

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html i can't use it for multiple statements which think update is?

Comment: so not sure how to go

Comment: @Uskompuf I am rather confused as to the overall scheme of your database. Is the "family" the CPU name? Can there be multiple CPUs to one particular title?

Comment: The name is the cpu e.g AMD Ryzen 5 2600 the family is e.g. Pinnacle Ridge. I have a preexisting table with cpu names i want to add the family's to the rows by matching the names up with the table. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Hi i just noticed that for entries with 2 pares of brackets it picks the last set not the first how can i fix this?